# Get Insert query with already inserted data from a table based On certain Conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, generate-scripts

I have a table named `sampletable`

and it has 10000 rows and i want to generate script (Insert query with inserted data) for this table based on certain conditions.

That is i need the insert query with data  for certain conditions

like `select * from sampletable where id=10` something like that

The select query will results 100 rows only so i need to get only this 100 rows as insert query statement with inserted values

I had tried

`Sql Management Studio` **Generate Script methods** but it results all rows.
I don't know how to do this please help me to solve this .

My purpose is i need to take backup of the  data (Only the Specific condition data not all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate an insert query by building a string, for example:

```
select  'insert into dbo.YourTable (str_col, int_col) values (' +
        isnull('''' + strcol + '''', 'NULL') + ', ' +
        isnull(cast(int_col as varchar(max)), 'NULL') + ');'
from    SampleTable
where   id=10
```

If it's a one-off job, you can use `Tasks->Export Data` and friends instead of manually crafting SQL inserts.

Comment: sorry how it will generate the insert query ??i need the data with insert query. i need to take back up of the data